# Eclipse(mars) jsf el expression (jboss tools)

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, jboss-tools

i have problem with el expression in jsf.

I installed jboss tools to have suggestions for properties on managed beans, and that works just fine.

The problem is when i open xhtml file in jboss tool html editor, or any other editor in eclipse, el expression is treated as plain text, a simple string.

So for example if i have value="#{textManagedBean.field1}" and i want to double click on field1 so i can select ONLY field1 i get whole string selected (from " to ").

On top of that in value="#{textManagedBean.field1}" i would like for textManagedBean.field1 to be in black and not blue...

http://imgur.com/fF6ffyl

I want it to behave same as in Netbeans, there it's acting as a peace of code, it gets black and all...

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can change color for Attribute values (Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Editor->Syntax Coloring->Attribute Values), but that's not exactly what you want I guess. You can log an feature request in JBoss Tools issue tracker here: issues.jboss.org (project "JBIDE", component "jsf"). Thanks!